# Google Desktop Client for Text Messaging

Tags: google-hangouts, google-voice, sms, instant-messaging

I know someone who wants to receive and respond to text messages from their desktop and am unfamiliar with Google's exploding messaging options.  Years ago I switched to Google Voice and I use Hangouts on the desktop for texting.

Is porting to Google Voice still the only option to maintain your existing mobile telephone number and be able to send and receive text messages from a desktop client?

Comment: As far as I know, most carriers offer a web-based client and/or an email interface to also view/write SMS messages. So it very much matters who your carrier is.

Comment: @ale I'm looking for a Google solution, which would be carrier independent.

Comment: Then Google Voice is it. Allo doesn't do SMS (and its desktop app is weird anyway) and Hangouts, last I heard, is having the SMS part of it ripped out and you need Voice anyway. GChat is gone. Project Fi is essentially a re-skinned Google Voice.